# Why should you use red Yoshi in Super Mario Run?

Tags: super-mario-run

Should you unlock Red Yoshi? I wouldn't understand why, as you always earn red Toads. I mean, reds are common. Can you please tell me why anyone would use him?

Answer (score 2):

Using the colored Yoshi increases the ratio of that color. If you play a level that contains red and blue Toads, you will get more red Toads when playing with the red Yoshi.

You would use this if, for some reason, you wanted more red Toads.